# How to disable dynamic view drop-down list in blogger.com website?

Tags: css, templates, blogger

I recently started a blog at blogger.com. My issue is this:

I selected a template to create the site. I like it except there is one part I don't like and want to remove. There is a dropdown list on the header bar that allows the visitors to change the layout of the site. This is called a dynamic theme, and is part of the template provided by blogger.com. I want to keep the rest of the template and theme, but just remove the drop-down menu that allows people to change the view.

I don't have experience with programming so I don't know what I'm looking at.

The settings do not allow this to be fixed, to the best of my knowledge and searching I believe I have to add CSS code, or maybe change the HTML code of the theme.

There are fixes provided when you I googled the problem however they are many years old and the new version of blogger.com isn't conducive to those fixes working anymore, and in some cases they just don't work and I don't know why.

I don't have experience with programming so I don't know what I'm looking at, here is the first 1/3rd of the HTML of the theme.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:dynamicViews='true' b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:lang='data:blog.locale' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>
    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
    <meta content='!' name='fragment'/>
    <meta content='dynamic' name='blogger-template'/>
    <meta content='IE=9,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
    <meta content='initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width' name='viewport'/>
    <b:skin><![CDATA[/*-----------------------------------------------
Blogger Template Style
Name: Dynamic Views
----------------------------------------------- */

/* Variable definitions
   ====================
   <Variable name="keycolor" description="Main Color" type="color" default="#ffffff"
         variants="#2b256f,#00b2b4,#4ba976,#696f00,#b38f00,#f07300,#d0422c,#f37a86,#7b5341" value="#ffffff"/>

   <Group description="Page">
     <Variable name="page.text.font" description="Font" type="font"
         default="'Helvetica Neue Light', HelveticaNeue-Light, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" value="&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;, HelveticaNeue-Light, &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"/>
     <Variable name="page.text.color" description="Text Color" type="color"
         default="#333333" variants="#333333" value="#333333"/>
     <Variable name="body.background.color" description="Background Color" type="color"
         default="#EEEEEE"
         variants="#dfdfea,#d9f4f4,#e4f2eb,#e9ead9,#f4eed9,#fdead9,#f8e3e0,#fdebed,#ebe5e3" value="#EEEEEE"/>
   </Group>

   <Variable name="body.background" description="Body Background" type="background"
       color="#EEEEEE" default="$(color) none repeat scroll top left" value="$(color) none repeat scroll top left"/>

   <Group description="Header">
     <Variable name="header.background.color" description="Background Color" type="color"
         default="#F3F3F3" variants="#F3F3F3" value="#F3F3F3"/>
   </Group>

   <Group description="Header Bar">
     <Variable name="primary.color" description="Background Color" type="color"
         default="#333333" variants="#2b256f,#00b2b4,#4ba976,#696f00,#b38f00,#f07300,#d0422c,#f37a86,#7b5341" value="#333333"/>
     <Variable name="menu.font" description="Font" type="font"
         default="'Helvetica Neue Light', HelveticaNeue-Light, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" value="&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;, HelveticaNeue-Light, &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"/>
     <Variable name="menu.text.color" description="Text Color" type="color"
         default="#FFFFFF" variants="#FFFFFF" value="#FFFFFF"/>
   </Group>

   <Group description="Links">
     <Variable name="link.font" description="Link Text" type="font"
         default="'Helvetica Neue Light', HelveticaNeue-Light, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" value="&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;, HelveticaNeue-Light, &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"/>
     <Variable name="link.color" description="Link Color" type="color"
         default="#009EB8"
         variants="#2b256f,#00b2b4,#4ba976,#696f00,#b38f00,#f07300,#d0422c,#f37a86,#7b5341" value="#009EB8"/>
     <Variable name="link.hover.color" description="Link Hover Color" type="color"
         default="#009EB8"
         variants="#2b256f,#00b2b4,#4ba976,#696f00,#b38f00,#f07300,#d0422c,#f37a86,#7b5341" value="#009EB8"/>
     <Variable name="link.visited.color" description="Link Visited Color" type="color"
         default="#009EB8"
         variants="#2b256f,#00b2b4,#4ba976,#696f00,#b38f00,#f07300,#d0422c,#f37a86,#7b5341" value="#009EB8"/>
   </Group>

   <Group description="Blog Title">
     <Variable name="blog.title.font" description="Font" type="font"
         default="'Helvetica Neue Light', HelveticaNeue-Light, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" value="&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;, HelveticaNeue-Light, &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"/>
     <Variable name="blog.title.color" description="Color" type="color"
         default="#555555" variants="#555555" value="#555555"/>
   </Group>

   <Group description="Blog Description">
     <Variable name="blog.description.font" description="Font" type="font"
         default="'Helvetica Neue Light', HelveticaNeue-Light, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" value="&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;, HelveticaNeue-Light, &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"/>
     <Variable name="blog.description.color" description="Color" type="color"
         default="#555555" variants="#555555" value="#555555"/>
   </Group>

   <Group description="Post Title">
     <Variable name="post.title.font" description="Font" type="font"
         default="'Helvetica Neue Light', HelveticaNeue-Light, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" value="&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;, HelveticaNeue-Light, &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"/>
     <Variable name="post.title.color" description="Color" type="color"
         default="#333333" variants="#333333" value="#333333"/>
   </Group>

   <Group description="Date Ribbon">
     <Variable name="ribbon.color" description="Color" type="color"
         default="#666666" variants="#2b256f,#00b2b4,#4ba976,#696f00,#b38f00,#f07300,#d0422c,#f37a86,#7b5341" value="#666666"/>
     <Variable name="ribbon.hover.color" description="Hover Color" type="color"
         default="#AD3A2B" variants="#AD3A2B" value="#AD3A2B"/>
   </Group>

   <Variable name="blitzview" description="Initial view type" type="string" default="sidebar" value="mosaic"/>
*/

/* BEGIN CUT */
{
 "font:Text": "$(page.text.font)",
 "color:Text": "$(page.text.color)",
 "image:Background": "$(body.background)",
 "color:Background": "$(body.background.color)",
 "color:Header Background": "$(header.background.color)",
 "color:Primary": "$(primary.color)",
 "color:Menu Text": "$(menu.text.color)",
 "font:Menu": "$(menu.font)",
 "font:Link": "$(link.font)",
 "color:Link": "$(link.color)",
 "color:Link Visited": "$(link.visited.color)",
 "color:Link Hover": "$(link.hover.color)",
 "font:Blog Title": "$(blog.title.font)",
 "color:Blog Title": "$(blog.title.color)",
 "font:Blog Description": "$(blog.description.font)",
 "color:Blog Description": "$(blog.description.color)",
 "font:Post Title": "$(post.title.font)",
 "color:Post Title": "$(post.title.color)",
 "color:Ribbon": "$(ribbon.color)",
 "color:Ribbon Hover": "$(ribbon.hover.color)",
 "view": "$blitzview"
}
/* END CUT */
]]></b:skin>
    <b:template-skin>
      <b:variable default='960px' name='content.width' type='length'/>
      <b:variable default='0' name='main.column.left.width' type='length'/>
      <b:variable default='310px' name='main.column.right.width' type='length'/>
      <b:variable default='46px' name='faviconpanel.height' type='length'/>

      <![CDATA[
      body {
        min-width: $(content.width);
      }

      .column-center-outer {
        margin-top: $(faviconpanel.height);
      }

      .content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner {
        min-width: $(content.width);
        max-width: $(content.width);
        _width: $(content.width);
      }

      .main-inner .columns {
        padding-left: $(main.column.left.width);
        padding-right: $(main.column.right.width);
      }

      .main-inner .fauxcolumn-center-outer {
        left: $(main.column.left.width);
        right: $(main.column.right.width);
        /* IE6 does not respect left and right together */
        _width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth -
            parseInt("$(main.column.left.width)") -
            parseInt("$(main.column.right.width)") + 'px');
      }

      .main-inner .fauxcolumn-left-outer {
        width: $(main.column.left.width);
      }

      .main-inner .fauxcolumn-right-outer {
        width: $(main.column.right.width);
      }

      .main-inner .column-left-outer {
        width: $(main.column.left.width);
        right: 100%;
        margin-left: -$(main.column.left.width);
      }

      .main-inner .column-right-outer {
        width: $(main.column.right.width);
        margin-right: -$(main.column.right.width);
      }

      #layout {
        min-width: 0;
      }

      #layout .content-outer {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 800px;
      }

      #layout .region-inner {
        min-width: 0;
        width: auto;
      }
      ]]>
    </b:template-skin>

    <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/thirdparty/jquery.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/thirdparty/jquery-mousewheel.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/common.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.localeUnderscoreDelimited != &quot;en&quot;'>
      <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc +           &quot;/js/languages/lang__&quot; + data:blog.localeUnderscoreDelimited + &quot;.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.view'>
      <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/&quot; + data:blog.view + &quot;.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
    <b:else/>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'>
        <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/classic.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
      <b:else/>
        <b:if cond='data:skin.vars.blitzview'>
          <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/&quot; + data:skin.vars.blitzview + &quot;.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
        <b:else/>
          <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/sidebar.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
        </b:if>
      </b:if>
    </b:if>
    <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/gadgets.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsCommentsSrc'/>
    <b:include data='blog' name='google-analytics'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='content-outer'>
        <div class='fauxborder-left content-fauxborder-left'>
          <div class='content-inner'>
            <div class='main-outer'>
              <div class='fauxborder-left main-fauxborder-left'>
                <div class='region-inner main-inner'>
                  <div class='columns fauxcolumns'>
                    <div class='column-center-outer'>
                      <div class='column-center-inner'>
                        <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='no'>
                          <b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' title='' type='PageList'>
                            <b:widget-settings>
                              <b:widget-setting name='pageListJson'><![CDATA[{'home': {'href': 'https://whattodowhenyoubored.blogspot.com/', 'title': 'Home', 'position': 0}, '4037426771495046110': {'href': 'https://whattodowhenyoubored.blogspot.com/p/cool-animals.html', 'title': 'Cool Animals', 'position': 1}, '8074300156492753576': {'href': 'https://whattodowhenyoubored.blogspot.com/p/cool-ideas.html', 'title': 'Cool Ideas', 'position': 2}, '52368681410083395': {'href': 'https://whattodowhenyoubored.blogspot.com/p/cool.html', 'title': 'Cool Things', 'position': 3}, '6916612229349686422': {'href': 'https://whattodowhenyoubored.blogspot.com/p/cool-people.html', 'title': 'Cool People', 'position': 4}, '3561598130147196418': {'href': 'https://whattodowhenyoubored.blogspot.com/p/ramblings-of-madman.html', 'title': 'Ramblings of a Madman', 'position': 5}}]]></b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='homeTitle'>Home</b:widget-setting>
                            </b:widget-settings>
                            <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'><h2><data:title/></h2></b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <select expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_select&quot;'>
        <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
          <option expr:value='data:link.href'>
            <b:attr cond='data:link.isCurrentPage' name='selected' value='selected'/>
            <data:link.title/>
          </option>
        </b:loop>
      </select>
      <span class='pagelist-arrow'>&amp;#9660;</span>
    <b:else/>
      <ul>
        <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
          <li>
            <b:class cond='data:link.isCurrentPage' name='selected'/>
            <a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a>
          </li>
        </b:loop>
      </ul>
    </b:if>
    <b:include name='quickedit'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
                          </b:widget>
                          <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>
                            <b:widget-settings>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showDateHeader'>true</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='style.textcolor'>#009eb8</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showShareButtons'>true</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='authorLabel'>Posted by</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showCommentLink'>true</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='style.urlcolor'>#555555</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showAuthor'>false</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='disableGooglePlusShare'>true</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='style.linkcolor'>#333333</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='style.unittype'>TextAndImage</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='style.bgcolor'>#ffffff</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='timestampLabel'>on</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showAuthorProfile'>false</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='style.layout'>1x1</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showLabels'>true</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showLocation'>true</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showTimestamp'>true</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='postsPerAd'>2</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showBacklinks'>false</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='style.bordercolor'>#ffffff</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showInlineAds'>true</b:widget-setting>
                              <b:widget-setting name='showReactions'>false</b:widget-setting>
                            </b:widget-settings>
                            <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
  <b:if cond='!data:mobile'>
    <!-- posts -->
    <div class='blog-posts hfeed'>

      <b:include data='top' name='status-message'/>

      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart and not data:post.isFirstPost'>
          &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
          &lt;div class=&quot;date-outer&quot;&gt;
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
          <h2 class='date-header'><span><data:post.dateHeader/></span></h2>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
          &lt;div class=&quot;date-posts&quot;&gt;
        </b:if>
        <div class='post-outer'>
          <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
          <b:include cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}' data='post' name='comment_picker'/>
        </div>

        <!-- Ad -->
        <b:if cond='data:post.includeAd'>
          <div class='inline-ad'>
            <data:adCode/>
          </div>
        </b:if>
      </b:loop>
      <b:if cond='data:numPosts != 0'>
        &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
      </b:if>
    </div>

    <!-- navigation -->
    <b:include name='nextprev'/>

    <!-- feed links -->
    <b:include name='feedLinks'/>

  <b:else/>
    <b:include name='mobile-main'/>
  </b:if>

  <b:include cond='data:top.showPlusOne' name='googlePlusBootstrap'/>
</b:includable>
                            <b:includable id='backlinkDeleteIcon' var='backlink'>
  <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:backlink.adminClass'>
    <a expr:href='data:backlink.deleteUrl' expr:title='data:top.deleteBacklinkMsg'>
      <img src='https://resources.blogblog.com/img/icon_delete13.gif'/>
    </a>
  </span>
</b:includable>
                            <b:includable id='backlinks' var='post'>
  <a name='links'/><h4><data:post.backlinksLabel/></h4>
  <b:if cond='data:post.numBacklinks != 0'>
    <dl class='comments-block' id='comments-block'>
      <b:loop values='data:post.backlinks' var='backlink'>
        <div class='collapsed-backlink backlink-control'>
          <dt class='comment-title'>
            <span class='backlink-toggle-zippy'>&#160;</span>
            <a expr:href='data:backlink.url' rel='nofollow'><data:backlink.title/></a>
            <b:include data='backlink' name='backlinkDeleteIcon'/>
          </dt>
          <dd class='comment-body collapseable'>
            <data:backlink.snippet/>
          </dd>
          <dd class='comment-footer collapseable'>
            <span class='comment-author'><data:post.authorLabel/> <data:backlink.author/></span>
            <span class='comment-timestamp'><data:post.timestampLabel/> <data:backlink.timestamp/></span>
          </dd>
        </div>
      </b:loop>
    </dl>
  </b:if>
  <p class='comment-footer'>
    <a class='comment-link' expr:href='data:post.createLinkUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_backlinks-create-link&quot;' target='_blank'><data:post.createLinkLabel/></a>
  </p>
</b:includable>
                            <b:includable id='comment-form' var='post'>
  <div class='comment-form'>
    <a name='comment-form'/>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <h4 id='comment-post-message'>
        <a expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_comment-editor-toggle-link&quot;' href='javascript:void(0)'><data:postCommentMsg/></a></h4>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' expr:height='data:cmtIframeInitialHeight' frameborder='0' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' style='display: none' width='100%'/>
    <b:else/>
      <h4 id='comment-post-message'><data:postCommentMsg/></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have many experience with Blogger´s dinamic templates but maybe something like this in the CSS:

```
#header .header-drawer.open {
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

The *#header .header-drawer.open* is ID and class of the header bar that allows visitors to choose the layout...

Or maybe like this:

```
#header #views {
  width: 0;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

*#header #views* is the ID for the dropdown in some dinaminc views. 
Without the link for your blog to check the code, this is all I can think of...